Number of Inversions in Inverse Transform Sampling from a Distribution
I understand the process of inverse transform sampling, but one component doesn't make sense to me:
The wikipedia article states:

In order to obtain a large number of samples, one needs to perform the same number of inversions of the distribution. One possible way to reduce the number of inversions while obtaining a large number of samples is the application of the so-called Stochastic Collocation Monte Carlo sampler...

I'm confused as to why we need to perform $n$ inversions to take $n$ samples.

Shouldn't inverting the distribution $1$ time be enough, and then we can just evaluate this same quantile function at different uniform random inputs to take different samples?

Definitely possible I'm misunderstanding something here. If they mean something different by this, in what scenario would you have to do $n$ inversions to take $n$ samples?
